# How to set protected variables in Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I tried to be good and make sure all my models were set up to protect against mass assignment.  My User class has an admin flag that is protected.

So what's the best way to set it?  All the blogs and RailsCasts I've seen that talk about the horrors of mass assignment seem to gloss over this part.

As is typical (I think?) I have my controller set up to use `update_attributes` as the conditional to determine whether or not the update worked and which flash message to display:

```
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

So when do I set the admin flag?  `update_attributes` doesn't take a block (at least not in Rails 2) so I can't set it there.

I'm thinking of setting and saving it in the success block of the `update_attributes` conditional.  This is all well and good for a simple admin boolean. What about something that would require actual validation?  Do you then need to have another if/else block to handle that save failing?

Should you set it before you call `update_attributes` and have the save part of the conditional?

```
if @user.save && @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Because that smells a bit to me.

As much as I don't like [DHH's idea](https://gist.github.com/1975644) of getting rid of mass assignment protection and using slice it would seem to solve this for me.

Or am I doing this all wrong?